# Can i show some web page on game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Screenshot]

Can i do something to show some web page on image in this case?
Without opening my web browser, or if i must open web browser i want it to take position and size of image on the display.

Answer (score 1):

-You can use the WWW class, it provides functions for sending and receiving data from a web site, but it won't help with the task of displaying one.

-Use Webkit for passing the textures to Unity with browser communication.(no interaction)

-Use an asset of the unity store, there are some for this task.

You can check this thread and get an idea, if you want to create your own asset for this, you should start reading documentation:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1297977/how-to-load-a-webpage-inside-an-unity3d-applicatio.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good asset called [3d webview](https://developer.vuplex.com/webview/overview) that I use for this. It has a prefab that you can add to your canvas and set its url in the editor.